# Launcher Theme In Android

Tags: android, themes

In my application, I've created a launcher theme for `MainActivity`:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
```

In another activity, I return MainActivity with:

```
startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply { flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP })
```

In the Android 10 emulator, when I returned `MainActivity`, the theme didn't re-render, but in the Android 11 emulator, the theme did re-render.
Target SDK in my app is 29.
Why did my app have different results on the two devices?
Is there a workaround for two devices to have the same result?